# OWIN Authentication Failing - Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, google-oauth, owin, facebook-oauth

I have some Web API applications that uses OWIN for authentication.  Currently they are hooked up to Google and Facebook.  I have them installed in multiple environments (local, dev, test, etc).  Recently ALL of my applications in my development environment started failing.  When trying to authenticate I would get a response back "access_denied".  The URL would look like this:

https://{mydevserver}/{mywebapiapp}/#error=access_denied

The same code base works locally as well as in my test environment.

I tried using the same project (just adding redirect uris and orgins) as well as creating a new project.

I also updated my test environment to use the dev project (id and secret).

Nothing seems to have changed on the server recently.  But it seems to be environment specific (because multiple applications are affected as well as multiple providers).

Are there any logging techniques I can use to drill down to a more detailed error message?  Any tips or hints for what to try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was a bit of an odd one.  I had to log into my server, open up a browser and connect to a web page (any page).  After doing so it started working again.